# MODX mSearch2 автоматический поиск

Tags: modx, search

Как можно сделать, чтобы при открытии страницы автоматически осуществлялся поиск по сайту и результаты выводились ниже? В качестве запроса для поиска должен выступать pagetitle страницы.

Например, мы находимся в блоге, заходим на страницу "строительство" и нам должны показаться результаты с другими страницами, на которых есть это слово.

Comment: вам на фриланс (1 символ)

Comment: удалось написать самостоятельно

Answer (score 1):

Решение в общем случае такое:
1. Пишите плагин, который при загрузке таких страниц кладет pagetitle в глобальный массив REQUEST
2. при вызове сниппета msearch2 в параметре &queryVar передаете имя переменной, куда сохранили pagetitle

Comment: Спасибо! У меня получилось сделать это через сниппет. Я создаю сниппет, в параметре которого указываю pagetitle ресурса, код сниппета: $_REQUEST['msearchQuery'] = $msearchQuery; return ''; И потом в queryVar  указываю msearchQuery.

Comment: Вы можете подсказать, как это исправить и каким должен быть код плагина и его событие, чтобы решить это с помощью 1 плагина?